# Global existence of solution of a differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-verification

I'd like to prove that given $f(t,x)$ Lipschitz on $x$ variable for every $[t_1,t_2]x\mathbb{R}^n$. The solution to the IVP is global (defined on $\mathbb{R}$). (with inicial value $x(t_0)= x_0$)

My approach:

Let $[t_1,t_2]$ an interval, I'll prove that the solution is defined on $[t_0,t_2]$. 
Let $J$ be the maximal interval on the solution and $x_m$ the solution which is defined on this interval, and let $S$ be its supremum.
If $t_2 \in J$ we're done. So, let's suppose that it's not.

$s \leq t_2$ and let $t_3= s-\frac{1}{4L}$ beeing $L$ lipschitz constant. 
Let $y$ be the solution to the IVP with inicial value $y(t_3)=x_m(t_3)$
By existence theorem $y$ is defined on an interval $ [t_3-\frac{1}{2L},t_3+\frac{1}{2L}]\subset I$.

But as $J$ was maximal $t_3+\frac{1}{2L} \in J $ but  $t_3+\frac{1}{2L}= s + \frac{1}{4L} < s$. ABS!

Then $t_2 \in J$ and the same argument gives that the solution is defined in $[t_1,t_2]$.

As this works for every interval, then the solution is global for every compact and that implies that the solution is global.

Comment: You should explain what you understand by "Lipschitz".  Does that mean that there exists $L > 0$ such that $\lVert f(t,x) - f(t,y) \rVert \le L \lVert x - y \rVert$ **for any $t \in [t_1,t_2]$ and any $x, y \in \mathbb{R}^n$**?  Further, as the right-hand side of the ODE is defined for $t$ belonging to $[t_1,t_2]$ only, your "global solution" is not defined on $\mathbb{R}$ but on $[t_1,t_2]$.

Comment: Basically what I meant by saying that it's Lipschitz on every $[t_1,t_2]$x$\mathbb{R}^n$ is the same that saying that is locally lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}$x$\mathbb{R}^n$.  ie what you said. About the other thing is that the same argument works for every closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$. I didn't explain it but it's strightfoward to see that if the solution is defined for every closed interval of $\mathbb{R}$ then it's defined on $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: What I wrote is certainly not **locally Lipschitz**:  that means that for each compact interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ and each compact $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ there is $L > 0$ such that $\lVert f(t,x) - f(t,y) \rVert \le L \lVert x-y\rVert$ for any $t \in I$ and any $x, y \in K$.  Then the solution $x(t)=\frac{1}{1-t}$ on $(-\infty,1)$ of $x'=x^2$ provides a counterexample.  Your proof is valid under the "global" assumption only (your Lipschitz constant $L$ is the same for any solution).